# Sum of functions with a changeable coeffcient by iteration

Tags: matlab

I am trying to program a code like below.

```
syms c, p
yfunc=symfun(0, [c,p])
y=[1 2 3 4 5] 
for j=1:5
       func=symfun((y(j+1)-c-p*y(j))^2, [c,p]);
       yfunc=yfunc+func;
end
```

I had expected that 'yfunc' would have five different functions of 'c' and 'p' in itself. But this code does not work. 
First of all, symfun cognizes y(j) as symbol not a value in a vector y. So I also tried to do like below instead of using symfun.

```
func=@(c,p)[(y(j+1)-c-p*y(j))^2]
```

But this works neither. Because in next line 'yfunc=yfunc+func' , plus is not allowed in function handle.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this,

```
syms c p

y = [1 2 3 4 5];
x = circshift(y, [1, 1]);

yfunc = symfun(sum((x-c-p*y).^2), [c, p]);
```

Your `for` loop would have gone out of bounds for `y` so I did a `circshift`. You could easily change that by saying `x(1) = ...` after the line assigning `x`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks specially for 'symfun(sum...' I never knew that

Comment: Honestly, neither did I, I just decided to give it a try.